# Safe to eat this ham?

Tags: ham

Took a boneless ham (shrink wrapped) out of freezer at 5 pm, and left it in sink all night, til 8 am. Room temp 65 degrees.  Is it safe to eat?

Comment: No. There is a food safety post someone will link you to. If the meat is above 40F for more than two hours it is likely spoiled. Of course you could still cook and eat it. It might taste bad, or it might make you sick. It might not. Doubtful you'll die, not impossible.

Comment: Note from @Caleb's comment: the *meat* above 40F, not the ambient temperature. But without measuring it you can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anyone is going to touch this, because of safety issues. My mom used to do this before all of those salmonella cartoons in the 1970s. We didn't know we got sick from the food back then. We thought we got a cold or flu.

My brother once got really sick from this.

Comment: Sensii, we don't shy away from food safety questions, the answer is pretty clear: *Not safe.* But we have a bunch of canonical Q/As where this question is a duplicate. And the rule is that we vote to close instead of answering again. (Plus it allows the duplicate to be deleted at some later time.)

Comment: Oh, and just to avoid any confusion: "not safe" is not the same as "spoiled" or "will make you sick".